# Make button go invisible after some time

Tags: android

I Want to make the my Button go invisible or gone a few seconds after the activity is created. Using a thread gave me this error

The Error is in here :

```
android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Then I tried using a Handler, this gave me this error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity `ComponentInfo{com.LstSearch/com.LstSearch.BasicMusicView}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

So then I  tried using runOnUiThread(). If I execute this in onCreate(), the activity takes the amount of time as I have specified in the thread, and the image will go invisible after that much time. But when the activity starts after 3 seconds, the image has already turned itself invisible.
I think have found the Solution as a new entry they are not allowing me to answer me question so i am editing here

```
handler=new Handler();
 Runnable r=new Runnable() 
{ public void run() 
{change image } 
};
 handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

Cheers!!

Comment: may you post your code and the log... and you may consider using AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call the invisibility function on the UIThread(), you can though views only in UIThread.

user `runonUIthread()` method.

Comment: It's not working as intended.Errors are not their but the code does nt have any impact

Comment: can you suggest me how to put my image in the bottom left of screen above all data and images as it will go invisible after 3 secs

Comment: runOnThread() if i execute this inside onCreate() the activity is taking as much time as i have specified in Thread so that the image will go invisible after that much time.but when the activity  starts after 3secs by that time image  already has changed it's status to gone

Comment: you have to start a handler , and use handler.postDelayed() method. it runs on UI thread by default and also you can specify delay in it.

Comment: where can i use this method as it's not working inside onCreate() i have used it prior to writing here.

Comment: handler=new Handler();
Runnable r=new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {change image                  
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);

Comment: Though you have nt provided me the solution but you have directed me. The above COde works for me.. anyway i am going to mark it as answer ..Thanks

Comment: handler=new Handler();
 Runnable r=new Runnable() 
{ public void run() 
{change image } 
};
 handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);